# State Info on Stack Overflow Developer Survey

Tags: stack, overflow, survey

Is it possible to obtain a subset of the Stack Overflow Developer Survey data just for the state of Michigan?

Comment: Thats not what the stack and overflow tags should be used for

Comment: Ask a meta question with your newly gained reputation :)